# leaflet doesn't show information from a geojson file

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm new in Leaflet and I'm trying to show some values associated to different countries in a world map. Leaflet only shows an empty map.

I use the following code:

```
// load GeoJSON from an external file
$.getJSON("convertcsv.geojson", function(data) {
    // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
});
```

The geojson file with the information has the following structure:

```
 {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [{
             "type": "Feature",
             "geometry": {
                 "type": "Point",
                 "coordinates": {}
             },
             "properties": {
                 "FIELD1": null,
                 "FIELD2": "Country",
                 "FIELD3": "Year",
                 "FIELD4": "Gender",
                 "FIELD7": "Longitude"
             }
         }, {
             "type": "Feature",
             "geometry": {
                 "type": "Point",
                 "coordinates": [33.7680065, 14.63608]
             },
             "properties": {
                 "FIELD1": 0,
                 "FIELD2": "Afghanistan",
                 "FIELD3": "1993",
                 "FIELD4": "Female",
                 "FIELD7": "66.2385139"
             }
         }, {
             "type": "Feature",
             "geometry": {
                 "type": "Point",
                 "coordinates": [33.7680065, 28.65191]
             },
             "properties": {
                 "FIELD1": 1,
                 "FIELD2": "Afghanistan",
                 "FIELD3": "1993",
                 "FIELD4": "All genders",
                 "FIELD7": "66.2385139"
             }
         },
```

Comment: What did you try? Please try to give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The goal is a colorpleth map considering the FIELD7 value and to filter those values regarding the year or gender. I started trying to show points in the different locations in the map but it doesn't show anything, only an empty map.

Comment: The coordinates for the first point are empty and that breaks Leaflet.

Comment: But removing the first point it doesn't show anything either

Comment: It does, at least with what you gave us : https://plnkr.co/edit/kRWWAdz9oEP8OsG6XSLW?p=preview

Comment: Maybe the proble is that I added before a map tile:

 var map = L.map('map').setView([43, 15], 2);

  // load a tile layer
  var Esri_WorldGrayCanvas = 
  L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
 attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ',
 maxZoom: 16,
 minZoom: 2
  }).addTo(map);

Comment: @RobertaGimenez that sounds like a different issue. Please open a new question with relevant details and code.